# Do communist-era state-published books fall under copyright protection?

Tags: copyright

I am wondering if books from the communist era in east Europe (specifically Bulgarian books, published around 1981), that are technical in nature and have been published from a state run publishing house, are copyrighted.

What if I am to translate such a book in to English and publish it as my own work (without hiding the fact that it is a translation of the original text), can I sell it or upload it to my website to generate add revenue?

Comment: Which particular country published the original works?

Comment: Bulgaria, 1981 year

Comment: In general, yes, they are copyrighted. You would have to look at that country's copyright laws to see if they were exempt from copyright, but even if there are such exceptions they usually only cover certain institutions, not all state-owned enterprises.

Comment: I think in the USA where some documents produced by the state at tax payers expense can be copied legally, they are still under copyright but have a license allowing the copying.

Comment: So, I can't even upload the book to Wikimedia? Maaan, I love copyright laws...

Comment: @amon what about books whose copyright is listed as belonging to state agencies?  Especially assuming the state no longer exists.

Comment: @grovkin It is rare that a state stops existing, and there's usually a successor state. For example, Russia and Ukraine claim to be successors of the USSR. However, Bulgaria has been an independent state continuously since the end of the Ottoman empire, so the issue doesn't arise.

Comment: @amon but are those claims actually seen as valid in all contexts?   Does the state of Bulgraria actually claim copyright of all the works whose copyright was held by the [People's Republic of Bulgaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Republic_of_Bulgaria)?

Comment: @grovkin I don't understand. Bulgaria is Bulgaria. It's the same state it has been for over 140 years, albeit with a constitutional reform and a name change in the early 1990s. The state doesn't have to claim anything. Unless Bulgaria gave these rights away, it necessarily still holds them. I mentioned the unrelated USSR because that's a notable example of a state ceasing to exist. I used the word “claim” solely because Ukraine's role is complex, with Russia being widely accepted as the successor of the USSR.

Comment: @amon you are talking abstractly.  But concretely, let's say a book has a copyright page which says that the copyright belongs to PRB.  Does that mean that it reverts to the modern state of Bulgaria or to the author?  Because I think the person asking the question is the author of the book.  And what is the law that governs this.

Comment: @grovkin If Bulgaria held a copyright during the communist era, and didn't do anything to release the copyright (such as by selling these rights, or by releasing them into the public domain), and if the rights haven't expired in the meanwhile, then it still holds these rights. Bulgaria didn't lose any rights just because the name of the country and the constitution was changed at some point. Whether copyright exists depends on the country of origin, but for other modalities such as duration of copyright the law in the country of use is relevant.

Comment: @amon I understand that you insist that it is the same state, but technically it isn't.  It is the same for some purposes, but not for others.  If you have the references to the legal resources which can justify what you are saying, then you are probably in a position to write a good answer to this question.  And you it can be made better by working those references into the answer.

Comment: @grovkin  Technically it *is* the same state even though fundamentally it has changed. Russia is not the same state as USSR, PRC is not the same state as the (original pre-1949) RoC, Islamic Republic of Iran isn't the same as the pre-revolution Iran. But Bulgaria did not end the Communist rule by a revolution with a completely new basis for statehood. The transition was technically done within the PRB framework using the amending procedure in PRB constitution.

Comment: @xngtng if that's the case, it should make it much easier to come up with an actual answer.  If it's the same country, then the answer should be based on the current existing laws of Bulgaria.

Comment: I know that in the US, documents published by the US Federal Government are Public Domain. I dunno about Bulgaria, though.

Answer (score 1):

The only question that may be disputed is the ownership of those copyrights; the copyright exists as a matter of international law since the 19th century (ca. 1886 depending on the signatory states joining) subject to the [Berne Conventional](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention). Bulgaria has been a signatory state in each of its state forms. The point made below is analogously applicable here: Just because the Soviet Union kept Bulgaria under autocratic rules, the cessation of the USSR would not mean the independent state of Bulgaria would be deprived of the copyright subject work of art; it is questionable what will remain with the state, and what could be reclaimed be individuals creating those materials, but it is clear that the copyright protection will not cease.

From the perspective of an author of copyright work of art:

If you can substantiate that you acted outside of your agency under autocratic rule while creating the original, especially, if you were persecuted and/or, in fact, trafficked, in general, I would say you could make a strong claim that you should be allowed at least to use your own work or if such facts are known to a potential claimant (e.g. the Member State of Bulgaria), you probably wouldn't have to worry much as they would likely not attempt to enforce any unjust law as they may end up on the European Court of Justice.

Comment: I think you are under the impression that the original text is my own work. It is not, I was born 10 years after the book was published.

Comment: @ViktorChernev Edited further.

Comment: It's far from being the only question.  For example, in the United States, any works produced by the Federal Government are exempt from copyright restrictions.  If the copyright on the textbooks is held by the Bulgarian state and if, at any point, the laws of Bulgaria made state-owned works similarly exempt from copyright restrictions, then any works whose copyrights became owned, or were already-owned, by the state of Bulgaria would become forever exempt from copyright restrictions.  So an answer would require examination of the laws of the state of Bulgaria starting from the publishing date.

Comment: Bulgaria was hijacked by the USSR, and the original authors except for those who are exempt from international asylum and refugee protections for partaking in oppression or partaking without such extent of coercion as be excused are, arguably, acted under coercion including in the creation of such works of art. And although this theory probably makes the matter rather complex, I lean on even saying that a substantial part of those copyrights go to their rightful owners as provided by internationally law regardless of their recognition by then or today's Bulgaria.

Comment: The last comment sounds like it's a good time to post a reminder that this site is for q&a about what the law happens to be, not what is should be.  "Bulgaria was hijacked by the USSR" is not a legal concept that currently exists.

Comment: Glad to explain: The classical branches of power were under the control of an external power to such extent that it is both recognized internationally to an extent to award asylum and refugee status to those who successfully fled, and in Bulgaria to have been under autocratic rule. This is fertile ground for invalidating any decree-based or coerced and therefor illegal, null and void contracts that would provide any claim on the works of art of those not having partaken, other than under coercion or blackmail, the oppression sufficient for persecution under international law. Good?

Comment: @kisspuska most residents of the USSR itself were its victims.  In fact, overwhelming majority of the immigrants from the USSR came to the US as refugees. This doesn't change much.  There were still jobs in Communist countries and some jobs paid more and came with more clout than others.  Receiving a commission to write a text book, which was to be used on a national level, would be a highly-prestigious job.  And since the author would know ahead of time that the work was commissioned by the state, this would be work for hire.  Gandhi retained copyright despite living in a British colony, btw.

Comment: You made an argument, however, it fails. It is not a lawful work for hire under international law; Bulgaria has been a party to the International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights since March 23, 1976; no later then its entry into force (probably earlier) all such contracts as a result of trafficking of persons, forced labor or slavery are null and void for them being illegal therefore invalid and unenforceable by the operation of int’l law. “Highly-prestigious” is not a legal category, a choice between dog sh— & primate feces is not really a qualitative difference, and forced either way.

Comment: Although the U.S. Supreme Court doesn’t have a long history of trying reverse what’s happened in historic scales since what’s happened happened; the ECtHR and the ECJ are doing a fairly diligent, human-centered job when things like this get before them. I’m going to say it simple: If a case about a contract or intellectual property assignment clause of an employment relationship were to get before either of these judicial bodies, the “contracts” would be nullified irrespective of the fact IP was created — it would simply remain with the author(s). Possibly there is case law on it already.

Comment: Regardless, the answer is not a really high-quality answer since it lacks the level of references to sources I normally thrive for to provide. I yield to any criticism in those regards, and encourage any improvements.